# Question about a proof in Nievergelt's Complex Analysis in One Variable

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have a question about the function $\lambda$ from Lemma 2. Why it says that $\lambda (z) > 0 \forall z \in \Omega$ ? It means that $\lambda$ is a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course.